How large would all the matter in the universe be if we compressed it to quark density?
If we took all the matter of the observable universe and put it into a ball and compressed it to the density of a neutron star, how large would it be? And similar for quark density.

What is "quark density?"  Other than that, this question is just a 30 second lookup of numbers from Wikipedia (or your favorite AI search helper).  I started an answer, and spent far more time formatting the numbers with mathjax than I spent actually gathering them.   If I knew what you meant by quark density, I could probably finish it off,.

relevant : http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/timlin.html#c1%22 .  and linke there  : http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/expand.html#c2

@anna v: Those links aren't relevant to my question. This question is only tangentially related to cosmology. It's simply trying to gauge just how much matter there is in the universe in an easy to visualise manner.

@Cort Ammon: Look up quark matter and quark star in Wikipedia.

@PM 2Ring: Why yes, how are we expected to observe the unobservable universe?

@PM 2Ring: I have though I expect when someone mentions the universe they mean the observable universe implicitly. The convention should be to mentioning the unobservable universe explicitly.

That's a recipe for confusion. Many questions have been asked here & elsewhere caused by confusion over "universe" vs "observable universe". IMHO, it's better to be explicit and avoid the confusion.

Readers of this question may enjoy my answer https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/41005/16685 where I "flatten" the Milky Way to a disc with the density of water. I also give figures for the flattened Solar System.

It's simply trying to gauge just how much matter there is in the universe in an easy to visualise manner. Then ask that question, not what you did ask, which is quite different.

The mass of ordinary matter in the observable universe is $10^{53} \text kg$.
The density of a neutron star is on the order of $10^{17}\frac{\text {kg}}{\text m^3}$.
By division, the volume of the universe at the density of the neutron star is $10^{36} \text m^3$.  This would be a sphere on the order of $10^{13} \text m$ in diameter.  That's about the diameter of the solar system.
Likewise, a quark star (which is what the OP said to look at in the comments) has a density of somewhere between $10^{16} \frac{\text {kg}}{\text {m}^3}$ and another value I found of $10^{20}\frac{\text {kg}}{\text {m}^3} \text{kg}$  At 3 orders of magnitude more dense, simple division gives us a volume of  $10^{33} \text m^3$, or a sphere of diameter $10^{11} \text m$.  That's about the distance between the Earth and Sun.

The only tricky part of this answer was looking up the lengths in Orders of Magnitude(Length).  There's a whole series of those pages on wikipedia that are really helpful for getting scale.  I recommend it!

It would be $10^{12}$ m not $10^{13}$ m in diameter though, so, in between Jupiter and Saturn

I don't remember if there are ten to the 80 or 82 baryons on the universe...I'll pick 81 since it's divisible by 3.
"quark" density is one baryon (1 GeV) per cubic fermi, so
it's a cube with a side:
$$ 10^{\frac{81}{3} - 15} = 10^{12}...=1\,{Tm} $$
wow. that's small.
BTW: you should find the Schwarzschild radius of that--should be about the size of the visible universe.

Is the BTW comment based on the analogy between cosmological horizon and black holes? If so, why is the analogy valid if BH's have no dark energy and the cosmological horizon distance is not directly related to the amount of matter within that horizon?

@PatoGalmarini it's not the sophisticated. It's just a curiosity.  The point of my answer is that you can do this stuff on a post-it with arithmetic, provided you remember 2 numbers. 3 if you're unsure of the number of spatial dimensions.

In addition to @Cort Ammon formal answer, it needs to be mentioned that such compression levels of matter can't be achieved even in theory.
Maximum compression of any mass is governed by Schwarzschild radius,- it's the smallest ball to which one can compress any clump of matter with mass $M$. After that ball becomes a black hole and you can't decrease it's size anymore, because it's already a black hole and so you can't make more dense version of it.
Wolfram alpha for observable universe gives minimum of $15~Gly$ radius, which would be about $32\%$ of current observable universe radius. So it seems that observable universe is already densely packed enough.
In addition, cosmological horizon radius, is about $c/H_0=c/(70(km/s)/Mpc)≈14~Gly$, and it says that light emitted at and further than cosmological horizon will never reach us because universe there expands too quickly, i.e. at space expansion speeds $\gt c$.
These pair of facts shows that observable universe baryonic matter is already pretty much densely packed (not much far from an ideal black hole) and so matter in the observable universe can't be compressed much more (like to the scale of our solar system, mentioned by @Cort Ammon post). Otherwise that would be unphysical.

Unless somebody creates full-fledged quantum gravity theory which deals with gravitational singularities. But up-to-now it's still unphysical as we don't have such valid theory yet.

